# How to find a line in .css file and then changing the correlated config between the following brackets

Tags: sed

Let me start off by saying I'm just starting to dabble in sed, awk and regex.

Here's what I need help with.

On ubuntu, in /etc/alternative/gdm3.css I have this config section:

```
.login-dialog-banner {
  color: #d6d6d1; }
```

I need it to be

```
.login-dialog-banner{
color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
font-size: 14;
text-align: center;}
```

I am lost on how to first find .login-dialog-banner and then change the data in the follow on { data }

Answer (score 2):

Would you try the following:

```
sed '
/\.login-dialog-banner[[:blank:]]*{/{   ;# if the specified 1st line is found
    $!{ n                               ;# and the current line is not the last line, then print it and read the next line
        s/.*color:.*/color: rgba(255,255,255,1);\
font-size: 14;\
text-align: center;}/                   ;# if the next line contains "color:"
                                        ;# then replace the line with the specified lines
    }
}' /etc/alternative/gdm3.css
```

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Thank you for your attention as well as for upvoting. The `$!` condition succeeds if we are not in the last line and it makes sure we can read next line.

Comment: I've updated my answer including the explanation above. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks a TON for adding nice explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try below `sed` as per your requirement stated in the question:

`sed '/^\.login-dialog-banner {/{N;s/color: #d6d6d1; }/color: rgba(255,255,255,1)\;\nfont-size: 14\;\ntext-align: center\;}/}' /etc/alternative/gdm3.css`

I'm searching for the line starting with string `.login-dialog-banner {` and then substituting the second line : `color: #d6d6d1; }` with your next required data.

If the above command is working for you, you can include `-i` option for edit the file inplace.

`sed -i '/^\.login-dialog-banner {/{N;s/color: #d6d6d1; }/color: rgba(255,255,255,1)\;\nfont-size: 14\;\ntext-align: center\;}/}' /etc/alternative/gdm3.css`

From `man sed`:

```
i[SUFFIX], --in-place[=SUFFIX]

              edit files in place (makes backup if SUFFIX supplied)
```